# How hard can it be to add a "rotate" action?

Tags: ipad, image-editing, photos.app

Can you guys teach me how to rotate an image so that when sent by email we actually send it in the right rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As of 2016 this functionality is now part of iOS's native photo app

*The following information pertains an iPhone, but I assume the iPad is identical in terms of features.*

Short Answer: You can’t rotate photos in the default iOS’s Camera Software; you need to install a third party utility, like PS Express (recommended and free):

[image: ps express rotate]

Comment: weird that we need to go to 3rd party apps for such trivial action.

Comment: The iOS is full of /facepalm things… ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the iOS photos app by tapping on the edit button on the toolbar at the bottom when viewing a photo, then choosing crop/rotate, then rotate.

Comment: you do understand that this question was made in **2010 right**?... when iOS was on [version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_4) :P

Comment: @balexandre Yes which is precisely why I provided an up to date answer with the latest information. This question appeared on the front page from an edit to the question, and I noticed that the current answer was insufficient. For more information about answering older questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23996/222623